# In R, how do I select/subset sites with values greater than a value, but then keep all sites that contain values less than the selected value?

Tags: r, select, filter, subset, unique

I have the following data (please let me know if the link doesn't work; it's my first time uploading to github):

https://github.com/scottr2012/test_r_data/blob/master/2017_Annual_Averages_ALL.csv

I have some data that has values for ANC. I need to select where any of the SITES have ANC > 150, but keep all years of that SITE, even if the ANC is below 150. Currently the code below removes some of the values (and years) below 150. I need all SITES where any of the years has ANC above 150. This code currently seems to only make a list of unique sites (where ANC >150 at any point), but doesn't bring over the rest of the data.

```
vtsss <- mydata[ which(mydata$PROGRAM=='VTSSS' & mydata$ANC >= 150), ] # Pick a subset, in this case, VTSSS

unique_vtsss <- unique(vtsss$SITE)

vtsss2 <- mydata[ which(mydata[unique_vtsss]), ]
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(mydata, unique_vtsss) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

Here's where I subset the data but it still will remove some years with ANC less than 150.

```
vtsss <- subset(mydata, PROGRAM == 'VTSSS' & ANC >= 150, 
select=c(PROGRAM, SITE, YEAR, ANC))
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a small example of data which resembles your csv and I think that subsequent code does what you are asking:

```
PROGRAM <- c('VTSSS', 'VTSSS', 'VTSSS', 'VTSSS', 'VTSSS', 'VTSSS','VTSSS','VTSSS','other') 
SITE <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C") 
YEAR <- c(2018, 2019, 2020, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2018, 2019, 2020) 
ANC <- c(1, 1, 1, 160, 160, 160, 1, 160, 160)
mydata <- data.frame(PROGRAM, SITE, YEAR, ANC)

vtsss <- mydata[ which(mydata$PROGRAM =='VTSSS'), ]
vtsss2 <- vtsss[ which(vtsss$ANC >= 150), ]
vtsss2 <- subset(vtsss2, !duplicated(vtsss2$SITE))
vtsss3 <- vtsss[ which(vtsss$SITE %in% vtsss2$SITE), ]
```

Comment: I skipped making a table with unique SITE values though, as I don't think it is really necessary.

Comment: using `unique()` will be more efficient - might not matter unless the data set is big

Comment: @BenBolker Yes indeed, that is why I added the comment. I couldn't immediately figure out how to make a unique dataframe and wanted to help ASAP. I have now added a line which makes a table vtsss2 with only unique values.

Answer (score 3):

I think it should work if you replace your last line of code with

```
vtsss2 <- mydata[ mydata$SITE %in% unique_vtsss, ]
```

?

Answer (score 1):

May be we need a `group_by` `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>%
   group_by(SITE) %>%
   filter(any(ANC >= 150 & !is.na(ANC) &  PROGRAM %in% "VTSSS"))
```